# Trying to extract value from hidden field closest to LI tag through jquery selector

Tags: jquery

i am trying to capture value stored in hidden field `hdnServiceCode` when user will click on `btnShipNow` button. so here i paste a sample html. i want when user will click on `btnShipNow` button then i want to extract value from `hdnServiceCode`  hidden field which is closest to `btnShipNow` button.

### here is my html

```
<div id="rec">
<ul>
    <li>
    <input type="hidden" value="65" id="hdnServiceCode">
    UPS Express Saver</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>24.47&nbsp;GBP</li>
    <li class="nobutton"><span id="rptPrice_ctl01_btnShipNow">Ship Now</span>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="rec">
<ul>
    <li>
    <input type="hidden" value="15" id="hdnServiceCode">
    UPS Express Saver</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>11.47&nbsp;GBP</li>
    <li class="nobutton"><span id="rptPrice_ctl01_btnShipNow">Ship Now</span>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

### here is my jquery code

```
$('.nobutton').live("click", function () {
        alert($(this).closest('ul').closest('div#rec').closest("hdnServiceCode").val());
    });
```

but the above code is not working. where i am making the mistake. please help me to capture value from hidden field which is closest to `btnShipNow` button. thanks

Comment: Your ids should be unique.

Comment: IDs have to be unique, you can use $(this).prev() inside a click handler on an li element, or $(this).parent().prev() in the span to get the li element preceding your Ship Now button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
 alert($(this).closest('#rec').find("#hdnServiceCode").val());
```

Probably you had lot of mistakes in your selector like

- misusing id selector
- unnecessary usage of closest multiple times

But mainly you should really use unique ids for the elements inside a DOM. Use a class for the elements which is currently having the id `hdnServiceCode` and use,

```
 alert($(this).closest('#rec').find(".hdnServiceCode").val());
```

Comment: thanks for reply. if i need to retrieve the text UPS Express Saver or UPS Express Saver etc then what more code i need to add?

Comment: if i need to extract only text from li tag not html then how could i do this? i need to extract UPS Express Saver the only text value...then how could proceed in code??

Comment: @Thomas `$(this).closest('ul').prev('ul').find('li').text()`

Answer (score 0):

here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/boatrokr/jB5a5/

I cleaned up the issue with matching IDs and used this:

```
$('.nobutton').click(function(){
    alert($(this).prev().text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As id Should be unique. so modify your codee and added class **hdn** to your field

```
<div id="rec">
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="hidden" value="65" id="hdnServiceCode1" class="hdn"/>
    UPS Express Saver</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>24.47&nbsp;GBP</li>
    <li class="nobutton"><span id="rptPrice_ctl01_btnShipNow">Ship Now</span>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="rec">
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="hidden" value="15" id="hdnServiceCode2" class="hdn"/>
    UPS Express Saver</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>11.47&nbsp;GBP</li>
    <li class="nobutton"><span id="rptPrice_ctl01_btnShipNow">Ship Now</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

your jquery

```
$('.nobutton').on('click', function () {
        alert($(this).closest('#rec').find(".hdn").val());
    alert($(this).closest('#rec').find("ul:eq(0)  li").text());
    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/2B9bY/1/)